# cakephp model chaining and retrieving results from multiple models

Tags: cakephp

I am in process of chaining multiple models. The goal is to retrieve the category for the keyword when I pass a keyword.

Models

```
Keyword 
 columns:
    id
    keyword
KeywordCategory
 columns:
  keyword_id
  category_id
Category
  columns:
   id
   category
```

The following are the association definitions that I made.

Keyword

```
var $hasMany = array(
                        'KeywordCategory' => array(
                                    'className' => 'KeywordCategory',
                                    'foreignKey' => 'keyword_id',
                                    'dependent' => true
                                    )
                    );
```

KeywordCategory

```
var $belongsTo = array(
                        'Keyword' => array(
                                    'className' => 'Keyword',
                                    'foreignKey' => 'keyword_id',
                                    'dependent' => true
                                    ),                   
                        'Category' => array(
                                    'className' => 'Category',
                                    'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
                                    'dependent' => true
                                    )
                    );
```

Category:

```
var $hasMany = array(
                        'KeywordCategory' => array(
                                    'className' => 'KeywordCategory',
                                    'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
                                    'dependent' => true
                                    )
                    );
```

My question is when I currently retrieve the Keyword category currently it will return something like following:

```
Array
(
    [Keyword] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [keyword] => rc
            [modified] => 
            [created] => 
        )

    [KeywordCategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [keyword_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [keyword_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I want to also return the Categories signified by category_id in the result. Can anyone suggest the change that I need to make?

Thank you

Comment: set your recursive to 2

Comment: thank you. that was pretty simple.

Comment: Or use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).